# How to fix 'On change' event for a textbox that causes a run-time error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form for entering address information into an access database. The page has a listview that updates as information is written into each of the textboxes. Each line has a separate textbox

I've found that if information is entered into one of the textboxes, removed (leaving the value at "") and then re-entered, a runtime error 5 occurs at the following line:

> key = CInt(Right(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key, Len(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key) - 3))

After testing a few times, I was able to find that this error would occur ONLY on line 2 - 5, not line 1 (I can post this here too if needed) and ONLY if the other boxes are "". I'm not sure why this is, but it may have something to do with adding lines to the listview?

```vb
Private Sub txtbx_Line2_Change()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim key, startIndex As Integer
Dim addLine, removeLine As Boolean

    If lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    key = CInt(Right(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key, Len(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key) - 3)) 'This is where the error is thrown
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Line2]" & _
            " FROM [tbl_Addresses]" & _
            " WHERE [AddressID] = " & key)

    addLine = False
    removeLine = False
    If IsNull(rst![Line2]) Or rst![Line2] = "" Then        'line is blank, so we're adding a line
        addLine = True
    ElseIf txtbx_Line2.Text = "" Then
        removeLine = True
    End If
    rst.Edit
    rst![Line2] = txtbx_Line2.Text
    rst.Update

    'change the text in the listview

    If addLine Then
        startIndex = lstvw_AllAddresses.ListItems("ln1" & key).index  'assume start index = Line1
        lstvw_AllAddresses.ListItems.Add startIndex + 2 - 1, "ln2" & key
        lstvw_AllAddresses.ListItems("ln2" & key).Selected = True
    ElseIf removeLine Then
        lstvw_AllAddresses.ListItems.Remove "ln2" & key
    End If

    If Not removeLine Then
        lstvw_AllAddresses.ListItems("ln2" & key).Text = rst![Line2]
    End If

Close_Exit:
    rst.Close

Good_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare Key correctly, and don't use CInt that fails for invalid expressions:

```
Dim key As Integer
Dim startIndex As Integer
Dim addLine As Boolean
Dim removeLine As Boolean

    If lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key) - 3 > 0 Then
        key = Val(Right(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key, Len(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key) - 3)) 
    End If
```

Comment: I tried switching CInt for Val and got the same error and tried declaring key the way you did and still got the error. Also, can you explain "invalid expressions"?

Comment: Then `Len(lstvw_AllAddresses.SelectedItem.key) - 3` is negative. That will always cause `Right` to fail.

Comment: It isn't negative on the form load, but is when something is added to the textbox after backspacing everything in it, it is. What can I do about that?

Comment: You could check for that and, if so, leave `key` with its default value of 0 (zero). See edited answer, please.

Comment: So it seemed like the issue was that at the end of the code, if removeline was true, it would set the key to 0 instead of what the key should be. this was causing a record not to be found. Using your code as a base, I checked to see if key was < 0. If so, key would be set to the correct ID (which was in a lable on the form)

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.